# Execute git command with release in Azure

Tags: linux, git, azure

I have an azure linux VM. I hosted my laravel app in `/var/www/myapp`.

I also use azure git repo for my laravel app. I created a pipeline to make a deploy in azure.

It works fine after release. But it recreates all files.I do not want to recreate all files with release I just want to fetch changed files from git repo with:

```
git fetch --all
```

I tried to run a bash script task with release. But git command unable to run. Azure release gives this error:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Ho can I solve this git issue at release time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a directory created with spesific owner it needs to be call git request with this owner.So the solution is changing file owner in linux vm like this:

```
chown -R user:user(which user can access ssh key. Not root user) directory/
```